# rtabmap+camera pose

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all, i am using rtabmap for mapping and stereo camera pose estimate. i am following tutorials of rtabmap and created map from stereo images that these images save at file (link tutorials: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Stereo-mapping#process-a-directory-of-stereo-images-in-ros) but when roslaunch the launch file, from 1035 stereo images, rtabmap give me 44 pose camera. how can set rtabmap that this give me camera pose for per stereo image?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274470/rtabmap+camera-pose/) by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add "`--Rtabmap/CreateIntermediateNodes true`" to [rtabmap_args](https://gist.github.com/matlabbe/5731ce3b2bc25ec5e0295a80c9f5f671#file-stereo_20hz-launch-L39). This will add empty nodes in the graph with their pose between nodes used for mapping. You may not have one pose per image if the odometry cannot process as fast as the images are published.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2017-10-29**:
thanks matlabbe